# NodeJS to poll data from N sources every X seconds

Tags: node.js

Is NodeJS a good choice to poll data from N third party sources over REST interface.

I need to (almost) parallelize this so that I can support real time updates.

**Question** - Is NodeJS a good choice for this?

Comment: Make sure the third party allows such rapid polling, otherwise you could end up rate limited and/or blocked/banned altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Another caveats are:

1. If the response is too large for each polling and it is rapid
   (perhaps in 100s of megas) then you must try to use multiple node
   processes.
2. Server response for each polling should be less than the interval time of polling cycle else you may hit a condition where the process may become unresponsive and will eventually fail.

You may choose to use reactive programming for this scenario. Try [Rx.js](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS). This will help you in handling the process in controlled manner.

Answer (score 0):

use setInterval function with X time and get data from any source or DB

```
var xSecond = 5000;// 5 second
setInterval(function(){

 request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
   }  
 })

},xSecond)
```